# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered to local machine

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, visual-studio-2010

```
public partial class EnterData : Form
{
    OleDbConnection myconn=new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Buddiez\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\working with databse\working with databse\database.accdb");

    public EnterData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EnterData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connString = string.Format("insert into test_database values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", Convert.ToInt32(txtsno.Text), txtName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtage.Text), txtBackground.Text, txtAddress.Text);
        OleDbCommand myConn = new OleDbCommand(connString, myconn);
        try
        {
            myconn.Open();
            myConn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Entry Updated");
            myconn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

i have configured the configuration manager to any CPU even than i m facing the same problem Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered to local machine... guide me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. This will install all of the necessary dependencies in order for the Access OLEDB driver to work correctly.

[You can get it here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)